# Finding the N highest values of a vector

Tags: python, numpy

How do I find the N highest values of an vector?
Let´s say I´ve got a vector:

```
arr = np.array([12.5, 13.6, −9.1, 17.5, 15.3, 10.5])
```

And N = 3

the output should then be:

```
np.array([13.6,17.5,15.3])
```

So the 3 highest values of arr are kept in the same order.

if N=4 the output should be:

```
np.array([12.5,13.6,17.5,15.3])
```

Comment: Clone the array. Order the cloned array. Remove all elements from nth position. Remove in order the elements from original array that arent on new array.

Comment: Is it important that the elements of the resultant array are in the order they were in in the previous array?

Comment: I suppose so @PatrickHaugh if not he just need to order it and remove the elements from the nth position on fowards

Comment: Yes, @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 1):

You might like [`heapq.nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) method. It allows you to take `n` largest elements of any collections using linear time. I.e. you don't need to sort your original collection spending `O(n*log n)` time.

```
import heapq

n = 4
print(np.array(heapq.nlargest(n, arr)))
```